# Large Discrepancy in AWS RDS Storage Usage

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS for PostgreSQL and I've noticed a large discrepancy in storage usage. My RDS instance is allocated 20 GiB of storage, but when I check the size of my database using the pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('my_database')) command, it reports that my database is only using around 2279 MB.

I understand that the total storage usage includes the actual data, system files, indexes, logs, and backups. However, it seems unusual that these elements would consume over 86% of the total storage. I have not recently deleted a large amount of data, performed a major version upgrade, or run a large batch job or heavy write operation.

Can anyone explain why there is such a large discrepancy in storage usage? Is there a way to get a more detailed breakdown of storage usage in AWS RDS?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: <shot in dark>In some systems there's "allocation" vs "actual" so a table may be allocated to be X size (1g) but only actually use (500mg) is it possible allocaitons are taking some of it?

Comment: 20GB is the minimum "allocation".  As far as I know this is not some technical restriction, it is just their accounting policy.  You have to pay for that amount, whether you use it or not.

Comment: [`Amazon RDS provides you the ability to select from 20GiB to 64TiB of associated General Purpose SSD storage capacity for your primary data set.`](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/pricing/#Database_Storage) The pricing calculator does let you go below the 20GiB, presenting proportionately lower price, but that configuration isn't available beyond that calculator, as an actual offer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain why there is such a large discrepancy in storage usage?

What RDS shows you is the size of the EBS volume attached to the container running your database engine and used for data storage.

EBS volumes are sort of virtual hard drives which exist outside of the containers and can be attached and re-attached to different workloads.

All the storage space in these hard drives (including the empty blocks) is at your sole disposal, is encrypted, and cannot be reused by other users. Therefore, you'll have to pay for it.

RDS is a wrapper over PostgreSQL, MySQL and other database engines. All these engines' architectures work with the abstraction of storage as provided by the underlying OS's filesystem. While it's possible for modern filesystems to change their size on demand, it's not a trivial task to do that without service interruption. That's why the increment in storage size [happens in steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.Autoscaling).

Other cloud database products (Google Spanner, Google AlloyDB etc.) decouple storage from the rest of database interfaces, so the way your data is stored internally is not abstracted by virtual hard drives. On these products, storage increments and pricing may happen at more detailed level.

> Is there a way to get a more detailed breakdown of storage usage in AWS RDS?

Only with what your database tools may provide.

Under the hood, it's just a hard drive, but AWS won't let you attach it to any old EC2 instance and see its contents.